# Can kafka publish messages to AWS lambda

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I have to publish messages from a kafka topic to lambda to process them and store in a database using a springboot application, i did some research and found something to consume messages from kafka
`public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> process(){}` however, im not sure if this is only used to publish the consumed messages to another kafka topic or can be used as an event source to lambda, I need some guidance on consuming and converting the consumed kafka message to event source.

Comment: Are you using auto managed Kafka cluster or you're using Amazon MSK?

Comment: MSK, I'm using something like this ` public class LambdaRequestHandler implements RequestHandler<?, Person> { @Override public Person handleRequest(? event, Context context) { // process event return processes event; } }` Here the '?' is the place holder for kafka message, how i get the kafka messsage as input –

Answer (score 1):

Brokers do not push. Consumers always poll.

Code shown is for Kafka Streams API, which primarily writes to new Kafka topics. While you could fire HTTP events to start a lambda, that's not recommended.

Alternatively, Kafka is already supported as an event source. You don't need to write any consumer code.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-now-supports-self-managed-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source/

This is possible from MSK or a [self managed Kafka](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html)

> process them and store in a database

Your lambda could process the data and send to a *new Kafka topic* using a producer. You can then use [MSK Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect.html) or run your own Kafka Connect cluster elsewhere to dump records into a database. No Spring/Java code would be necessary.

Comment: ah that makes sense, I'm using something like this 
` public class LambdaRequestHandler
    implements RequestHandler<?, Person> {

  @Override
  public Person handleRequest(? event, Context context) {
   
    // process event
   
    return  processes event;
  }
}`
Here the '?' is the place holder for kafka message, how i get the kafka messsage as input

Comment: Seems fine if you only want to print json to Cloudwatch logs